# Kik Messenger/free texting app

Tags: ubuntu-touch, instant-messaging

I'm planning on buying the upcoming Ubuntu phone, and I'm curious to know if there's any free text/chatting apps for ubuntu phones, for example kik messenger or whats app. Since I would like to be able to still text with my friends without having to pay massive amounts.

Answer (score 3):

You can see all the apps currently available for the Ubuntu Phone at this site:

https://uappexplorer.com/

So far Telegram seems to be the most popular messaging app available for this platform.

Comment: Does anyone know if there has been any updates to this? I know whatsapp is available in the web app, but i still cannot see Kik.